# Error: missing revert data in call exception while testing with Hardhat

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I want to test get my function **TokenUri** using **hardhat**.
Here it is:

```
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory){
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), ".json")) : "";
    }
```

I want to query the URI of a token that does not exist. The test should fail and be reverted with "*ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"*

Here is my test with hardhat (tokenId 1 does not exist):

```
  it("should not work", async function () {
    let uri = await this.deployedContract.tokenURI(1);
    console.log(uri);
    await expect(uri).to.be.revertedWith(
      "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );
  });
```

I **npx hardhat test** then I have this error "*Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string*" followed by a huge error block.

[image]

To let you understand what "**This.deployedContract**" is:

```
  it("should deploy the smart contract", async function () {
    const baseURI = "ipfs://cid/";
    const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("test");
    this.deployedContract = await Contract.deploy(baseURI);
  });
```

Does someone encountered the same issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working. I think the error came from the fact that I used "await" before "*this.deployedContract.tokenURI(1)*" which do not return a promise.

[image]